# Formula for maximum coverage of a geostationary satellite based on earth station elevation

Tags: coordinate-system, contour, satellite, footprint

I am trying to create a JavaScript function to represent the maximum coverage of a geo satellite for different antenna elevations (0 degrees, 5 and 10 degrees) with 3 leaflet polylines.

The result is similar to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoVisibleRegion.html (see "The visible region from geostationary orbit", the contour in the example is for an elevation of 0 degree).

Any hint is welcome, I only found partial formulas on google.. it is not very clear

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do it on server-side?

Comment: it would be the same for me, I am using node so it's also in javascript. The missing part is the algorithm